# Python string length generate output

Tags: python, string

I am trying to create ruler by print, it should look like this for input value 5:

[image]

Im trying to change in my code numbers to symbols, my code is:

```
length = str(input("Enter the ruler length = "))


def ruler(string):
    top = []
    top_out = []
    bottom = []
 
    for i in range(length):
        top.append((i+1)//10)
        bottom.append((i+1)%10)
        for i in range(length):
            if ((i+1)//10) == 0:
                top_out.append(" ")
            elif (((i+1)//10) in list(sorted(set(top)))) and (((i+1)//10) not in top_out):
                top_out.append(((i+1)//10))
            else:
                top_out.append(" ")
                print (''.join(list(map(str, top_out))))
                print (''.join(list(map(str,bottom))))
                print (string)
```

How to correct it to get appropriate output format of a ruler?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592. **What happens** when you try your code? **How is that different** from what you want to happen? **Why** do you think the difference is there? What happened when you tried to find a solution for this yourself? Specifically where and why are you stuck - what don't you understand, about what the code is doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ruler printing can be down by pretty small function like this,

```
def print_ruler(n):
    print('|....'*(n)+'|')
    print(''.join(f'{i:<5}' for i in range(n+1)))
```

Execution:

```
In [1]: print_ruler(5)
|....|....|....|....|....|
0    1    2    3    4    5    

In [2]: print_ruler(10)
|....|....|....|....|....|....|....|....|....|....|
0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10   

In [3]: print_ruler(15)
|....|....|....|....|....|....|....|....|....|....|....|....|....|....|....|
0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10   11   12   13   14   15
```

For double-digit numbers, It doesn't come to the center.

For ex: For `12`, `|` align with number `1` or `2` it can't not make into the center of `12`

Comment: For larger numbers, e. x. 12 ruler's number aren't under '|'.

Comment: Better add the space in the format itself: `f'{i:<5}'`

Comment: So how to correct this? I also wanted to start it from 0.

Comment: @MalumPhobos Sorry I miss read the question. updated it.